# How to add extra C language library programing enviorment in the docker where chaincode is executing?

Tags: c, docker, docker-compose, hyperledger-fabric

I want to use pairing-based cryptography library which doesn't have a go language version in my chaincode.

I have run the official example 'e2e_cli'.
Using Command 'docker ps', we can see nine dockers.

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                 COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                                                       NAMES
846a361282bb        dev-peer1.org2.example.com-mycc-1.0   "chaincode -peer.add…"   19 minutes ago      Up 19 minutes                                                                                   dev-peer1.org2.example.com-mycc-1.0
1cae2900a68a        dev-peer0.org1.example.com-mycc-1.0   "chaincode -peer.add…"   20 minutes ago      Up 20 minutes                                                                                   dev-peer0.org1.example.com-mycc-1.0
7b6de20b250b        dev-peer0.org2.example.com-mycc-1.0   "chaincode -peer.add…"   21 minutes ago      Up 21 minutes                                                                                   dev-peer0.org2.example.com-mycc-1.0
d9ab459a1f85        hyperledger/fabric-tools              "/bin/bash -c './scr…"   22 minutes ago      Up 22 minutes                                                                                   cli
91ec21c0632f        hyperledger/fabric-peer               "peer node start"        23 minutes ago      Up 23 minutes       0.0.0.0:8051->7051/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8052->7052/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8053->7053/tcp      peer1.org1.example.com
e028c96b2d6c        hyperledger/fabric-peer               "peer node start"        23 minutes ago      Up 22 minutes       0.0.0.0:7051-7053->7051-7053/tcp                                            peer0.org1.example.com
08d057bc084f        hyperledger/fabric-peer               "peer node start"        23 minutes ago      Up 23 minutes       0.0.0.0:10051->7051/tcp, 0.0.0.0:10052->7052/tcp, 0.0.0.0:10053->7053/tcp   peer1.org2.example.com
2be6cf82c41e        hyperledger/fabric-orderer            "orderer"                23 minutes ago      Up 22 minutes       0.0.0.0:7050->7050/tcp                                                      orderer.example.com
6e084f144bb1        hyperledger/fabric-peer               "peer node start"        23 minutes ago      Up 22 minutes       0.0.0.0:9051->7051/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9052->7052/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9053->7053/tcp      peer0.org2.example.com
```

I think the docker named 'dev-peer0.org1.example.com-mycc-1.0' is the place where chaincode is executing in node 'peer0.org1'.

So I need to add pbc library programing enviorment to the docker like 'dev-peer0.org1.example.com-mycc-1.0'.

But 'dev-peer0.org1.example.com-mycc-1.0' is created automatically while chaincode is installed and instanced, I couldn't find the way to add the libray.I didn't find volumes path like 'volumes:' settings in file 'docker-compose-cli.yaml'.

```
cli:
container_name: cli
image: hyperledger/fabric-tools
tty: true
environment:
  - GOPATH=/opt/gopath
  - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
  - CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=DEBUG
  - CORE_PEER_ID=cli
  - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
  - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP
  - CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
  - CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/server.crt
  - CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/server.key
  - CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt
  - CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp
working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer
command: /bin/bash -c './scripts/script.sh ${CHANNEL_NAME}; sleep $TIMEOUT'
volumes:
    - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
    - ./../chaincode/go/:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/examples/chaincode/go
    - ./crypto-config:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/
    - ./scripts:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/scripts/
    - ./channel-artifacts:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/channel-artifacts
depends_on:
  - orderer.example.com
  - peer0.org1.example.com
  - peer1.org1.example.com
  - peer0.org2.example.com
  - peer1.org2.example.com
```

Here is the part I use PBC library in my chaincode.

```
package main
/*
#cgo LDFLAGS: -L. -lpbc -lgmp -lcrypto
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "pbc/pbc.h"
int myfunc(char * keyword)
{
/*C language codes using PBC library*/
char *str_pairing= "type a\nq 878071079966331252243778198475404981580688\
31994142082110286533992664756308802229570786251794226622214231558587695823174\
59277713367317481324925129998224791\nh 12016012264891146079388821366740534204\
802954401251311822919615131047207289359704531102844802183906537786776\nr
7307\ 50818665451621361119245571504901405976559617\nexp2 159\nexp1 107\nsign1 1\nsi\gn0 1";
pairing_t pairing;
element_t a,b,c,d,e,g,h,r;

pairing_init_set_str(pairing, str_pairing);
element_init_Zr(e, pairing);
element_random(e);
element_init_G1(g, pairing);
element_random(g);
element_init_G1(h, pairing);
element_pow_zn(h, g, e);
element_init_G1(a, pairing);
element_init_G1(b, pairing);
element_init_G1(c, pairing);
element_init_GT(d, pairing);
element_init_Zr(r, pairing);

element_random(r);
element_pow_zn(a, g, r);
element_pow_zn(b, h, r);
element_from_hash(c, keyword, strlen(keyword));
element_pairing(d, c, b);
........
}
*/
import "C"
import "unsafe"
import (
"fmt"
"strconv"
"os/exec"
"github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/shim"
pb "github.com/hyperledger/fabric/protos/peer"
)
……/*go language codes*/
```

Comment: I'm not sure which pairing algorithms you are trying to use, but you might want to take a look at the Milagro AMCL library which does have a Go version and I know it supports BLS signatures.  See https://github.com/milagro-crypto/amcl/tree/master/version3/go

Comment: Are you attempting to add C/C++ source code or are do you want to link an external library?

Comment: I'm trying to use Bilinear mapping.I want to link an external C language library - PBC library.I hope to add PBC library in the container. So I want to know how the 'dev-peer0.org1.example.com'  container builds its enviorment.Thanks@GariSingh

Answer (score 0):

I recompile the image--hyperledger/fabric-ccenv:x86_64-1.0.0, added the library I need.Because the chaincode is compiled in a container which is run base on fabric-ccenv image.